# Как можно скрыть рекламу Adsense для определенного разрешения экранов?

Tags: javascript, php, google-adsense

В логах метрики видно, что на сайт много заходов с разрешением экрана 360x720, 360x780, 320x694, 412x869, 412x846. Я полагаю, что это боты.
За день в аналитике набегает в районе 50 боткликов по рекламе (15% от общего числа).
Как мне ограничить показ рекламы для "подозрительных" разрешений экранов?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) и для подозрительных разрешений поставить `display: none;` на `<ins class="adsbygoogle" ...>` теги.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что `display: none` как-то запретит ботам нажимать на рекламное объявление

Comment: При `display: none` adsbygoogle.js не загрузит рекламу и ботам будет не почему кликать.